# How to skip elements before certain document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Background:
I am writing a mobile application which has lazy loading page. My backend is using go and mongodb with mongo-go driver. There are 10 elements on that page and i want to get next ten when i scroll to the bottom. I am planning to send ObjectID (_id) as request query parameter and get next ten elements starting from the index of id + 1.

I write what i want in mongo shell "language" so that more people understand what i want and can help in shell syntax.

Is there a way to get index of the document by it's _id or may be i can get skip until it in skip().

something like `db.collection.find().skip(idOfDocument+1).limit(10)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://scalegrid.io/blog/fast-paging-with-mongodb/?source=post_page---------------------------).

nextDocuments = db.collection.find({'_id'> last_id}).limit(10)